# Simply display a local PDF file in a React web-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, web-applications

I am making a portfolio website for myself as a React webapp. I would like to have a Resume page on the website which would simply display my Resume. When I had originally made a HTML version of my website I could achieve this with iframe.

When I've tried this in React the iframe display a copy of the current display page instead of my pdf. Is there a simple way to just display a pdf saved locally in the webapp?

Comment: What do you mean by "local", exactly?

Comment: As in, the pdf is saved in the resource files of the application, so there is no need to download or fetch any file from the internet

Comment: @Acinea A "web app" **is** downloaded from the Internet, albiet in-pieces, by the user's web-browser - but you sound like you're talking about a _React Native_ (not ReactJS) application or something like that. While ReactJS applications can be bundled-up into a small number of files using tools like Webpack and Rollup it would be bad practice to somehow embed a PDF file in there (I guess as a Base64-encoded `data:` URI? _ew_) so you are very mistaken if you think the "resources files of the application" have "no need" to be downloaded from the Internet.

Comment: @Dai Thanks for the insight, I am very new to programming/React.

I've been playing with my issue more. I am still trying to use Iframe to display my pdf file. The website shows the iframe as being totally blank. In the devtools I have an "Issue" pop up saying "Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode", which as I am understanding is due to there being no Doctype for the import pdf file? Do you know of anyway to fix this?

Comment: @Acinea If you have any questions about QuirksMode/DocType that belongs in a new StackOverflow posting, let's not derail this thread.

Comment: @Dai I am still trying to solve the same issue in the stated question. I am using React as a Portfolio Website, I want a page to display my resume. Looking for the simplest way to make that happen. I was just sharing my current obstacle, but if you know of a better way I would value your input.

Comment: Just include the PDF file when you publish/deploy your website to your webhost and load the PDF into a same-origin `<iframe>`. If using an `<iframe>` isn't working for you right now then that might be because you're using `file:///` URIs instead of `https://localhost` - in which case you aren't programming for ReactJS properly as you should be using a running `node` environment with localhost server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any Browser « Use _Embeddable Google Document Viewer to embed the PDF file in iframe.

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?
url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true"
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0">
```

I am not sure what does it mean " display a copy of the current display page"
You can provide more information with screenshot.
Also you can use pdf from googleDocs instead of storing pdf in your project .

Comment: Thanks for the response, what I meant was that the iframe is displaying the exact same picture as the actual webpage (its just mirroring whatever is already on the screen.

After playing with it alittle more, I noticed I am getting this error when using the iframe. "Page layout may be unexpected due to Quirks Mode". This error says it is effecting the pdf I am trying to load, and the iframe is just blank

Comment: " iframe is displaying the exact same picture as the actual webpage (its just mirroring whatever is already on the screen"     . Can you confirm that you can see the pdf in your web page , or you mean you cannot edit it and you can just viewing it ? Can you please provide the example screenshot . You can edit the post and drag the screenshot and drop .

Comment: @ThanHtutZaw Found my issue! It was a strange bug, when I had the Chrome Dev Tools open, the Iframe would not render the pdf; however, when the Chrome Dev Tools is closed, it renders just fine. Thanks for trying to help me!

Comment: Glad to help . I also made this example . https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-microservice-761691

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `<embed>` tag in your HTML.

For example the following format displays the pdf document at the given path with the width of 150% and 650pixels.

```
<embed src="/path/to/your/pdf" width="100%" height="600px" />
```

You can adjust the width and height as you want to fit it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

When I try this the embed element renders as a copy of the current page I am on in the React app, despite setting the source to the pdf file, any idea what could be causing this?